# Closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$

Tags: summation, closed-form

Find the closed form of
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$$

Comment: You should edit your question to indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Hint:  Try using a partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Note that $$\dfrac{2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\dfrac{1}{2k-1}-\dfrac{1}{2k+1}.$$

This leads to $$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{(2k+1)(2k-1)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n \left( \dfrac{1}{2k-1}-\dfrac{1}{2k+1}\right).$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes.Thanks for the help.